# How can I use Parallel.ForEach to read the columns of an csv file header?

Tags: c#

I have to read a huge csv file and wanted to use Parallel.ForEach to make the reading faster. But when I debug it the identification of the columns goes out of order. There is an correct way to do this?

```
StreamReader _headerReader = new StreamReader(folder);

string[] header = _headerReader.ReadLine().Split(',');

int headerColumn = 0;
int firstColumn = 0;
int secondColumn = 0;
int thirdColumn = 0;

// And etc...


Parallel.ForEach(header, content =>
{
    switch(header[headerColumn])
    {
    case"First"
        firstColumn = headerColumn;
        break;

    case"Second"
        SecondColumn = headerColumn;
        break;

    case"Thrid"
        thirdColumn = headerColumn;
        break;

    // And etc...

    }
    headerColumn++;
}
```

I wanted to place the number of each column in each column variable, but the numbers never come on the correct order.

Comment: How huge are we talking here?

Comment: @HansPassant Read the code.  He's reading sequentially, processing parallel.  He doesn't understand parallel is all.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to explain **what the code is trying to do** and how long it is currently taking.

Comment: Are you sure parallelizing this will improve performance (noticably)? Usually when I/O is involved, the bottleneck will be reading the file, not processing it.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking `Parallel` to process an array of strings in multiple threads, then ignoring the `content` parameter to roll your own indexing to the array, without any control over when the loop variable is changed.

Imagine you have two threads running your code, and that the threads are out of sync.  Let's see what happens...

```
    Thread1                 Thread2                         headerColumn
1   switch (header[headerColumn])                           0
2   case "first":                                           0
3   firstColumn = headerColumn;                             0
4                           switch (header[headerColumn])   0
5   break;                                                  0
6                           case "first":                   0
7   headerColumn++;                                         1
8                           firstColumn = headerColumn;     1
9                           break;                          1
10                          headerColumn++;                 2
```

On line 7 Thread1 increments `headerColumn` after Thread2 has tested the value but before it assigns the value to `firstColumn`.  So both threads assign a value to `firstColumn`, neither thread ever modifies `secondColumn` at all, etc.

And that's a massive over-simplification.  In reality multiple threads can be executing *simultaneously* on different CPU cores.  If the increment operation is implemented as a series of instructions (`load;increment;store` for instance) instead of an atomic or interlocked increment then you could end up with `headerColumn` being less than you expected if multiple threads conflict during increment.

Instead you should generate the index outside of the parallel section and pass it in, along with the header name.  Something like this:

```
headers.Select((name, index) => new { name, index })
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll
    (
        header =>
        {
            switch (header.name)
            {
                case "First":
                    firstColumn = header.index;
                    break;
                case "Second":
                    secondColumn = header.index;
                    break;
            }
        }
    );
```

That said, you're not going to see much of a speed increase unless you're working on hundreds of columns... and writing this code against hundreds of columns is going to be just horrible.

There are plenty of good CSV readers out there.  [`CsvHelper`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) for instance, which has automatic mapping between CSV and classes so you don't have to handle headers yourself, you just read a sequence of objects.

It can be fun to reinvent the wheel, and you can certainly learn a lot, but there's a lot to be said for not wasting time on things that other people have already made solutions available for.